# IOError when trying to append to a file in Cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, append, ioerror

I have a very simple little python script to demonstrate my problem:
*The codeblock below is the complete script, totally 5 rows, stored in a file named t.py*

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as myfile:   // Open file.txt in write mode
    myfile.write("a b c ")              // Write “a b c “ to the file

with open("file.txt", "a") as myfile:  // Open the file.txt in append mode
    myfile.write("d e f")               // Append “d e f” to the end of the file
```

The script works fine when i execute it from windows command prompt. I then end up with file.txt containing "a b c d e f", as I want it.

However, when I execute the same script using python in Cygwin I get error when trying to write 'd e f' to the file. (IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument) I then end up with file.txt containing only "a b c "

Python version: 2.7.x
Cygwin version: 1.7.20

Do someone have any idea what could be the cause?

Here is the full stack trace:

```
$ python t.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "t.py", line 5, in <module>
      myfile.write('d e f')
IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Here is the **exact** (directly copy & paste from p.py):

```
with open("simtest_test_report.csv", "w") as myfile:
    myfile.write("a b c ")

with open("simtest_test_report.csv", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write('d e f')
```

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace please?

Comment: Yes, Added stack trace.

Comment: Based on what you've pasted I can't see a problem here.

Comment: Is it worth posting the full-code from that "t.py" file?  I suspect there's another problem at play here.

Comment: Belive it or not, but it is actually the full-code. There are only 5 rows in my script, t.py.

Comment: Could you post it anyway? The *exact* code.  Copy and paste it in - just so we can be sure it is identical.  The code in the answer should work.  I'm concerned there may be some difference from when you originally put the code in (as you already had an extra space for example).

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the space you've got on the second file name:

```
with open("file.txt ", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("d e f")
```

See how there's a trailing space there - which you didn't have with the previous file name.

Comment: Oh. That was accidentally added by me during the creation of this post. The script does not have any space characters. I have modified my post regarding this. Thank you